# JQuery nth-child selector only works with :nth-child(1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert something after every 4th div, this is my Jquery for it:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter(".top-car-img :nth-child(4n)");
```

However, this is not working. But if i replace the `4n` with a `1`, then it works and every element gets the p-tag. Why doesn`t it work when i try it with every 4th element?

Comment: Show your HTML structure. [Your code should work](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk9gfgrc/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("<p>Test</p>").insertAfter('.top-car-img:nth-of-type(4n)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="top-car-img" title="1" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="2" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="3" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="4" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="5" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="6" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="7" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="8" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="9" src=""/>
<img class="top-car-img" title="10" src=""/>
```

Comment: OP asking **I am trying to insert something after every 4th div** not after only the 4th element

Comment: Why do you thin `each` is needed? It shouldn't be needed according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Comment: You are right. It isn't nessecary. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the space between the element and the child.

Example:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter(".top-car-img:nth-child(4n)");
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdMLyq

Comment: Absolutely no change if i do this, same result.